Condition for infinite solutions to matrix linear equation.
For a matrix equation AX=B it is known that a there are infinite solutions for the matrix X if

|A|=0
(adj A)B = O

Consider the following situation

Satisfies the condition for infinite solutions, yet there are no solutions to the planes
x+y+z=1
x+y+z=-1
What's wrong?

$|A|=0$ is equivalent to $Ax=b$ has an infinite number of solution or $Ax=b$ has no solution.

@Mark Dinh But what about the second condition to determine whether it has infinite solutions or no solution? That is not being satisfied here.

You have an implication, not an equivalence. $Ax=b \Rightarrow adj(A)Ax=adj(A)b \Rightarrow |A|x=adj(A)b$. In your example, $|A|=0$ and $adj(A) = 0_{3\times 3}$.
